# Catching Foreign Key Exception in POSTGRESQL

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a java program that does an insert into the PostgreSQL database.

Currently I get a `org.postgresql.util.Psqlexception` with no SQL state and code if there is an FK error. I think this is a generic error type for all db level errors.

Is there any way that I can modify the behaviour so that I can distinguish between an FK error and just a generic db error?

thanks

Comment: Are you saying that `SQLException.getErrorCode()` does not return a proper error code? Please show us your Java code. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Did you try to get the [ServerErrorMessage](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/ServerErrorMessage.html) and look into [it](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/ServerErrorMessage.html)?

Comment: Hi. No i didn't. Thanks for this feedback. Let me give that a go.